# Java: error al llamar JPanel desde JFrame

Tags: java

Tengo una clase que hereda de JFrame y se muestra la vista, en la vista tengo un boton donde llamo a otra clase que hereda de JPanel pero no se abre la nueva vista, espero y me puedan ayudar.

> JFrame

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

//HEREDA DE JFRAME
public class Index extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new Index().setVisible(true);   
}

//Atributos
private JTextField txtJugador1, txtJugador2;
private JButton btnIngresar;
//private JLabel labelImagen;
private JLabel lBienvenido, lblJugador1, lblJugador2;
//private JTextField txtJugador2;

//Constructor
public Index () {
    getContentPane().setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 204));
    this.setSize(400, 310);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setResizable(false);

    Font estilo = new Font("Andale Mono", Font.PLAIN, 14);

    lblJugador1 = new JLabel("Nombre (jugador 1)");
    lblJugador1.setBounds(99, 46, 174, 30);
    lblJugador1.setFont(estilo);
    this.getContentPane().add(lblJugador1);

    txtJugador1 = new JTextField();
    txtJugador1.setBounds(99,  88, 174, 30);
    txtJugador1.setFont(estilo);
    this.getContentPane().add(txtJugador1);

    lblJugador2 = new JLabel("Nombre (jugador 2)");
    lblJugador2.setBounds(99, 130, 174, 30);
    lblJugador2.setFont(estilo);
    this.getContentPane().add(lblJugador2);

    btnIngresar = new JButton("Ingresar");
    //btnIngresar.addActionListener(this);
    btnIngresar.setBounds(99, 241, 174, 30);
    btnIngresar.setFont(estilo);
    getContentPane().add(btnIngresar);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setResizable(false);

    lBienvenido = new JLabel("Bienvenido");
    lBienvenido.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lBienvenido.setBounds(149, 7, 138, 30);
    getContentPane().add(lBienvenido);

    txtJugador2 = new JTextField();
    txtJugador2.setFont(new Font("Andale Mono", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    txtJugador2.setBounds(99, 172, 174, 30);
    getContentPane().add(txtJugador2);

    btnIngresar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Jugador jugador = new Jugador();
            jugador.setJugador1(txtJugador1.getText());
            jugador.setJugador2(txtJugador2.getText());
            //mandamos a la ventana del juego
            Juego juego = new Juego();
            juego.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("si entra");
        }
    });

}
} // termina la clase
```

> JPanel

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Juego extends JPanel {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

Pelota pelota = new Pelota(this);
    ArrayList <Pelota> pelotas = new ArrayList<>();
    Raqueta raqueta = new Raqueta(this);
    Raqueta raqueta2 = new Raqueta(this);//se crea la segunda raqueta
    int aceleracion = 10;

    public Juego() {
        establecerEscuchadorDeTeclado();
        setFocusable(true);
        pelotas.add(pelota);
        raqueta.Y = 330;
        raqueta2.Y = 30;
    }

private void move(){
        for (int i = 0; i < pelotas.size(); i++) {
           pelotas.get(i).mover();
        }
        raqueta.mover();
        raqueta2.mover();//se mueva la segunda raqueta
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            for (int i = 0; i < pelotas.size(); i++) {
                pelotas.get(i).visualizar(g2d);
            }
            raqueta.visualizar(g2d);
            raqueta2.visualizar(g2d);//visualizo la segunda raqueta
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Caso de estudio");
    Juego game = new Juego();
    frame.add(game);
            frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setSize(300, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    while(true){
        game.move();
        game.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(game.aceleracion);

    }

}

    private void establecerEscuchadorDeTeclado() {
        addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                raqueta.keyPressed(e);
                raqueta2.keyPressed(e);//teclas con las que se va a mover
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                raqueta.keyReleased(e);
                raqueta2.keyReleased(e);
            }
        });
    }

    public void gameOver() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "GAME OVER", "\nEl juego ha terminado", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        System.exit(ABORT);
    }
}
```

Comment: te falta agregarlo add(juego);

Comment: Hola, podrias explicarme un poco mas?

Comment: te respondi revisalo

Answer (score 1):

Te falta agregar tu `jpanel` al `jframe`, te falta agregarlo `add(juego);`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Jugador jugador = new Jugador();
            jugador.setJugador1(txtJugador1.getText());
            jugador.setJugador2(txtJugador2.getText());
            //mandamos a la ventana del juego
            Juego juego = new Juego();

juego.setVisible(true);
getContentPane()..add(juego);
            System.out.println("si entra");
        }
```

Comment: Me marca error, dice que cree el metodo Juego

Comment: Pasa lo mismo que lo de @Stefan Nolde, no se muestra mi segunda vista

Answer (score 0):

Tu creas el JPanel en una variable local, pero nunca lo agregas al JFrame.

```
btnIngresar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Jugador jugador = new Jugador();
        jugador.setJugador1(txtJugador1.getText());
        jugador.setJugador2(txtJugador2.getText());
        //mandamos a la ventana del juego
        Juego juego = new Juego();
        // eso no te sirve para nada:
        juego.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("si entra");
    }
});
```

Tienes que juntar el panel al frame, así puedes declarar un campo en el frame y asignar el `juego`a este campo, o simplemente lo agregas al frame como:

```
btnIngresar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Jugador jugador = new Jugador();
        jugador.setJugador1(txtJugador1.getText());
        jugador.setJugador2(txtJugador2.getText());
        //mandamos a la ventana del juego
        Juego juego = new Juego();
        getContentPane().add(juego);
        juego.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("si entra");
    }
});
```

Si quieres mas control como o donde se te muestra, agrega un JPanel en Tu frame donde te conviene, nombralo por ejemplo `JPanel juegoHolder` y agrega el juego a este panel.

```
btnIngresar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Jugador jugador = new Jugador();
        jugador.setJugador1(txtJugador1.getText());
        jugador.setJugador2(txtJugador2.getText());
        //mandamos a la ventana del juego
        Juego juego = new Juego();
        ((Index)getContentPane()).juegoHolder.add(juego);
        juego.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("si entra");
    }
});
```

Un poco mas elaborado sería, agregar un [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) a tu gui y luego colocar juegos nombrados en este JPanel con la opción de cambiar entre juegos agregados con la api de `CardLayout`. Quizas sería para una refacturación con eventualmente una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Hola, agregue unicamente el getContentPane().add(juego); no marca error pero no se muestra la segunda vista

Answer (score 0):

Pues hubiese sido mas fácil que todo lo que visualizas en un principio en el `JFrame` lo hagas en un `JPanel` agregas todos los componentes al `JPanel` y luego lo colocas al `JFrame` así al tu llamar al panel del juego, Ocultas el `JPanel` del Formulario y colocas el panel del juego si no te los muestra es por los controles del `JFrame`.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Jugador jugador = new Jugador();
            jugador.setJugador1(txtJugador1.getText());
            jugador.setJugador2(txtJugador2.getText());
            //mandamos a la ventana del juego
            Juego juego = new Juego();
add(juego);
            juego.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("si entra");
        }
```

Asi llamas al JPanel del juego.